# Problem with R code: Computation failed in `stat_signif()`: not enough 'y' observations

Tags: r, statistics, significance

I am trying to compare two groups with 47 observations in each and tried to include the significance level using **ggsignif** but it gives me this error message :
Computation failed in `stat_signif()`:
not enough 'y' observations
This is the data :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qy1D.png)

The first group being "Un-C_SL" / "Un-C_RL" / "Un-C" and the second one that doesn't appear in the image is "Vp_SL" / "Vp_RL" / "Vp"

This is the code I used:

```
ggplot(UnC_Vp_2, aes(x = Condition, y = Biomass)) + geom_boxplot() + geom_signif(comparisons = list("Un-C", "Vp"), map_signif_level = TRUE)
```

I was able to get the box plot but not the significance level. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The `comparisons =`  argument needs a `list()` of pairwise comparisons that are each contained in a `c()`, so it should work if you change it to `comparisons = list(c("Un-C", "Vp"))`.

[See this github issue also](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/164). I found this question when I had the same problem; I had forgotten it needed to be a list and not just `c()` and I agree that a more informative error message would help.

Comment: I am sorry for the delayed response, @kt.leap, I had it figured a little later after posting the question. Thank you, anyway!